# VBA ADO Excel-2010 Refrence table with SQL insert

Tags: vba, excel-2010, ado

I have code to wright an insert from one excel workbook to an external workbook. When I insert a row it works but the table the data is in doesn't increment. Is there any way other then opening the workbook to have to row increment as I insert a new row from my VBA code from a external workbook????

```
 Public Function insertComment()
   Dim tablename As String
   tablename = "sheet1"


   Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
   Dim conn As ADODB.connection
   Dim prm1 As ADODB.Parameter
   Dim prm2 As ADODB.Parameter
   Dim prm3 As ADODB.Parameter
   Dim connectionString As String
   Dim SQL As String

   Set conn = New ADODB.connection
   Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

   DBPath = "path\to\file\workbook1.xlsm"
   connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
  SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tablename & "$] ([QuestionID], [EvidenceID], [Data]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

    'Open connection
    conn.Open connectionString

   'Set command text
   cmd.CommandText = SQL
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

   'Set connection
   cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

   'Set paramters in SQL query
    Set prm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm1
    cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = 1

   Set prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm2
   cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = 2

   Set prm3 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p3", adInteger, adParamInput)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm3
   cmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = 3


   cmd.Execute
   conn.Close
End Function
```

Comment: do you want to insert question marks in the table?

Comment: No, I have to put ? marks because the driver I am using doesn't recognize variable names.

Comment: `?` in VBA is a wildcard and you cannot use it in the SQL statement directly. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: If I use variables in the query it won't recognize it. i need to use the ? mark. This code works fine but what happens is it will add a new row to a worksheet and not extend the table inside. I want a new row added to the table inside the worksheet so I can access the worksheet with pivot tables.

Comment: use Excel tables so you can have your data structures and select the table as the source data for your pivot table, it is very easy. To add a new row to your table use `tbl.listrows.add` where `tbl` is the Excel table where you can define it like this: `dim tbl as listobject` and `set tbl=worksheets("Sheet1").listobjects(1)` instead of 1 you can use the name of table too

Comment: Thanks but my issue with that is I don't want the workbook opening up. Since I am using ADO I want to add the data to an external workbook without using WorkBook.Open.

Comment: You cannot add sth to a workbook without opening, however you can open it invisibly

Comment: Well what I mean is the workbook doesn't open on the users computer having two workbooks opened in one excel instance. So your saying open the workbook invisibly then close it? How well does that work?

Comment: Your code does not cover all of the things you say. You need to show us what piece of code opens the workbook and once you inserted the data, you need to save the workbook and close it. how often the users need to write data in the WB? how many users are you talking about?

Comment: I don't open the workbook. I create the connection and run my query then close the connection.

Comment: I am not sure you can insert data into a workbook without opening it regardless of the method you are using. Also,I am not sure your code is executing ok and why do you need to use ADO for that, you want to insert some data in a workbook, simply use VBA. ADO is for applying SQL queries which in here looks unnecessary

Comment: I am making a data entry tool with an excel workbook which inserts a new row into an external workbook. I am doing this because I want to allow multiple people to insert data into the same external workbook. Using ADO opens a connections then I close it but to the best of my knowledge doesn't open the workbook as a new instance or in my VBA project. Using Workbook.Open actually shows the workbook which is what I am trying to avoid. This code works since excel is ODBC compatible. However I can't reference a table or know how to I can run SQL on a worksheet.

Comment: why don't you use an Access DB? excel is not a DB tool and you are trying to make it harder. Also, you can define tools to export data from the Access DB

Comment: I am limited to what I have available to me but yes I would love a database.

Comment: I think your right and I should just open the workbook hide it do what i want then close the workbook.

Comment: Opening a WB and closing it would not take more than 5 seconds so you should be fine, however you can make sure whether the WB is already open or not. If it is open, then you wait 3 seconds and you can do this for 3 attempts and if it did not work you give back the user TRY AGAIN. Plus, ADO does not provide concurrency or record lock, that is provided by the DB engine, which is not available in Excel, if you want that then you have to go with Access